# HTML5 Hyperlink end linking

Tags: windows, html, google-chrome

I want the hyperlink to apply to the image only but do not know how to end the linking.

It continues to link the header and other text blocks below my hyperlink line.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  How do I isolate the hyper link to just the image? I am using google chrome as my browser

Here is my code:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"
    <title>Example Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is Craig's Favorite Dog.</h1>
    <p>Click on image for more information.
    <article>
    <dd><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_(dog)">
    <img src="https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2016/04/newfoundland-    dog.jpg" height="240" width="360"
    </a></dd>       
    </article>
    </p>
</body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2>This is the fart of the dog<h2>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="fart.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source src="fart.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>


</html>`
```

Comment: You didn't add a ">" at the end <img> tag after "360". Replace your <a href> code with this : <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_(dog)">
    <img src="https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2016/04/newfoundland-    dog.jpg" height="240" width="360">
    </a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *image* tag is not terminated - finish it with a greater than character (i.e. `>`).

```
<img src="https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2016/04/newfoundland-dog.jpg" height="240" width="360" />
```

Also note that I added a slash (`/`) before the end of the tag. That is because *image* tags have no permitted Content - [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img):

> **Permitted content**  None, it is an empty element.

Other suggestions:

- Don't add the closing body tag (`</body>`) before the rest of the contents are added (e.g. the *h2* tag, the *audio* tag, etc).
- Permitted content for the paragraph tag (`<p>`) is [*Phrasing content*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) but the *article* tag is [*flow content*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) so just move the article tag after the paragraph tag.
- The closing tag for the [heading 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) towards the end is missing the closing character: `</h2>`

See [this plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/khozYrzDmNVfuE0lFrc8?p=preview) with the updates applied

Comment: Thanks for looking this over! Appreciate your help, Sam!